# Inserting data into a 'custom post type' table from the front end

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Hay, i need to make a wordpress plugin that logs all emails from a contact form. I'm thinking about using a 'custom post type' so that the admin can see all the emails in the admin area.

Can i manually insert data into this table? I'm thinking about writing a script which saves the emails when the email has been sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dotty,

You can create a custom post type and then, you'll need to use the wp_insert_post function ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post ) to be able to send info from the front end.

So your plan of attack would be to use register_post_type ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type ) to create your CPT, then in your plugin you'd set the 'post_type' argument for the wp_insert_post function to the name of the CPT you created.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the emails in the database and query them.